# jquery for -> syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

im here new. I've made a isotope portfolio for my page but i have a little problem.

The problem is in my jquery code, i've tried jsfiddle and jshint but gives me error on line where is closeing tags.

```
 });
```

and this is original code

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < isotopeBreakpoints.length; i++ ) {
        if (windowWidth >= isotopeBreakpoints[i].min_width || !isotopeBreakpoints[i].min_width) {
            if (windowWidth < isotopeBreakpoints[i].max_width || !isotopeBreakpoints[i].max_width) {
                $container.find('.portfolio-item').each(function() {
                    $(this).width( Math.floor( $container.width() / isotopeBreakpoints[i].columns ) );
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems a valid code, the jshint suggestion is to __Don't make functions within a loop.__

Comment: That's not the whole code, is it?

Comment: You might want to link your fiddle.

Comment: Irvin domnin thanks for comment, i just copied part of code to jsfiddle and tried it, a copied a loop to jsfiddle and its ok now, thanks. CLOSED

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a valid code, the `jslint` suggestion is:

> Don't make functions within a loop

Ref: http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

A possible solution is to move the inner function in an external function and call it inside the loop.